# Python - Update to single element is affect all elements in same column

Tags: python, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to create a connect 4 class, but whenever I drop a letter/token, it updates the entire column. I can't figure out for the life of me why this is happening:

```
class ConnectFour():
def __init__(self, width, height):
    self.width = width
    self.height = height        
    self.board = [[0] * width] * height

def dropLetter(self, letter, col):
    count = self.height - 1
    while count > 0 and self.board[count][col] != 0:
        count -= 1
    print self.board[count][col] 
    self.board[count][col] = letter     
    print self.board

C = ConnectFour(4,4)
C.dropLetter('X', 0)
```

Then when I print self.board, every slot in the provided column is updating. Why is this happening?

Comment: `[[0] * width] * height` is your issue.

Answer (score 4):

Problem is here:

```
self.board = [[0] * width] * height
```

When you do so, `self.board` contains `height` references to the same row of `[0]*width`. Now you need to change it to

```
self.board = [[0]*width for _ in range(height)]
```